# Запретить выделение на всей странице, кроме полей ввода

Tags: css

Мне нужно, чтобы на всей странице нельзя было выделять элементы. Но при этом можно было нормально работать с полями ввода типа `input, textarea`. Я знаю, что для этого нужно использовать

```
user-select: none;
```

и

```
user-select: text;
```

И соответственно с префиксами `-moz, -khtml, -webkit, -ms`.

Но если я ставлю, например, для всех дивов `user-select: none`, то неважно, какое свойство стоит у элемента input. Всё равно не будет возможности выделять текст в поле мышью. Если же я ставлю `user-select: none` только для body, то все элементы продолжают быть выделяемыми. Если поставить для дивов `user-select: none`, то эффект тот же - их можно выделять.

Каким образом вообще решается такая задача: запретить выделение мышью на всей странице произвольной структуры так, чтобы можно было нормально работать с полями ввода???

Answer (score 1):

делайте что-то типа:

```
 * { user-select:none; }
 * input, * textarea { user-select:text; }
```

чем точнее путь, тем больше у него приоритет